# hibernate save record netbeans

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, netbeans-8

i have problem in netbeans this page was working 100%
idk today i was checking my work since i have review
This error came when i want save booking information im not sure why :(

java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

this is my java code pls if you can help i will appreciate it

```
     import java.util.List;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
    
    
        @ManagedBean(name="Bookingbean")
    @RequestScoped
    
    public class BookingTicket  implements java.io.Serializable {
        
          public SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        public Transaction transaction;
        public Session session;
        public  Configuration cfg;
        
    
    
         private int tid;
       
         private String movieName;
     
         private String row;
         
         private Integer noTicket;
         private Double total;
       
         private Integer card;
       
        
         private Integer phone;
       
         private Double price;
        
         private Integer rownum;
    
         public String mname;
         
         
         
         public double movieprice;
         
         
        public BookingTicket() {
              cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            sessionFactory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
    
        
        public BookingTicket(int tid) {
            this.tid = tid;
        }
        public BookingTicket(int tid, String movieName, String row, Integer noTicket, Double total, Integer card, Integer phone) {
           this.tid = tid;
           this.movieName = movieName;
           this.row = row;
           this.noTicket = noTicket;
           this.total = total;
           this.card = card;
           this.phone = phone;
        }

 public int getTid() {
        return this.tid;
    }
    
    public void setTid(int tid) {
        this.tid = tid;
    }
    public String getMovieName() {
        return this.movieName;
    }
    
  

      public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
            this.movieName = movieName;
        }
        public String getRow() {
            return this.row;
        }
        
        public void setRow(String row) {
            this.row = row;
        }
        public Integer getNoTicket() {
            return this.noTicket;
        }
        
        public void setNoTicket(Integer noTicket) {
            this.noTicket = noTicket;
        }
        public Double getTotal() {
            return this.total;
        }
        
        public void setTotal(Double total) {
            this.total = total;
        }
        public Integer getCard() {
            return this.card;
        }
        
        public void setCard(Integer card) {
            this.card = card;
        }
        public Integer getPhone() {
            return this.phone;
        }
        
        public void setPhone(Integer phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }
    
        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }
    
        public Transaction getTransaction() {
            return transaction;
        }
    
        public void setTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
            this.transaction = transaction;
        }
    
        public Session getSession() {
            return session;
        }
    
        public void setSession(Session session) {
            this.session = session;
        }
    
        public Configuration getCfg() {
            return cfg;
        }
    
        public void setCfg(Configuration cfg) {
            this.cfg = cfg;
        }
    
        public Double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    
        public void setPrice(Double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    
        public Integer getRownum() {
            return rownum;
        }
    
        public void setRownum(Integer rownum) {
            this.rownum = rownum;
        }
    
        public String getMname() {
            return mname;
        }
    
        public void setMname(String mname) {
            this.mname = mname;
        }
        
        public String display()
        {
            mname=movieName;
            return mname;
        }
    
        public double getMovieprice() {
            return movieprice;
        }
    
        public void setMovieprice(double movieprice) {
            this.movieprice = movieprice;
        }
        
        
                
        
        
         public List<BookingTicket> showAllRecordsticket()
        {
            //step 4
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                    Query query = session.createQuery("from BookingTicket");
                    List<BookingTicket> ticket = query.list();
                    transaction.commit();
                    
            return ticket;
        }
        
        
        
        
        public double  totalno()
        {
             if(movieName.equals("After"))
                  { movieprice = 3.000;}
             else if (movieName.equals("Black"))
                  { movieprice = 4.000;}
             else if (movieName.equals("The Greatest showman"))
                  { movieprice = 3.000;}
             else { movieprice = 3.000;}
           // total=(price + rownum) * noTicket;
           total = (rownum + movieprice) * noTicket;
            return total;
        }
        
    
    

   public  void saveTicket()
{
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(new BookingTicket(getTid(),getMovieName(),getRow(),getNoTicket(),getTotal(),getCard(),getPhone()));
    transaction.commit();
    
}
```

idk where is the problem thats why i wrote almost all java code becouse it was really working :"( and this is the strack trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.validate(RegexValidator.java:163)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1248)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:1037)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1334)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:757)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1298)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:269)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1298)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1298)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1332)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:77)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Kindly share stacktrace

Comment: @Mohammad okay done !